# Standard Deviation of a Fraction

Tags: standard-deviation

If the average proportion of people who cycle is 15% across various countries and the standard deviation of this proportion is 0.94 or 94% across countries, how can this be interpreted?

Answer (score 5):

It is impossible for the standard deviation of any probability distribuiton restricted to the interval [0,1] to exceed 0.5

Comment: In the paper I am reading the variables were transformed using log(x/1-x). Using this, the average fraction is -0.74 and S.D is 1.2. Solving for x I get 0.154 for the average fraction and 0.94 for the S.D. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what do you mean, solving for x?

Comment: What I am guessing is that you set log(x/1-x)=1.2 and solved for x.  If that is the case, you are indeed doing something wrong.  For clarity, I will refer to log(x/1-x) as "logit(x)". The standard deviation of logit(x) is not the same as the logit of the standard deviation of x.  That's your mistake.

Comment: So they say that x is the original series value and they transform it using log(x/1-x). In this case x is the fraction of the population that cycles. so if log(x/1-x) is reported to equal -0.74, (x/1-x)=10^-0.74 etc. Re-arranging I got x=0.154 or 15.4% of the population cycles. But the S.D in this form is 1.20 and when I apply the same procedure as above I get that it equals 0.94.

Comment: yup, see my above comment.  The logit of the standard deviation is not the same thing as the standard deviation of the logit.

Comment: Ok, so does this 0.94 actually represent anything? Or how can I get the standard deviation of the fraction of people that cycle?

Comment: well, .94 is the standard deviation of the logit.  This is frequently a more meaningful concept than the standard deviation of the fraction, because the fraction is restricted to the interval [0,1] and so will not be approximately normally distributed.  Often, the logits of fractions are roughly normally distributed, which is a common reason for applying logit transformations in order to do statistics on fractions.

Comment: Just to spell it out clearly, imagine my dataset consists of two observations, .01 and .99.  The standard deviation of this dataset is ~0.5.    
I transform to a new dataset:  logit(0.01) ~ -2, and logit(0.99) ~ 2.  The standard deviation of this dataset is 2.  But the logit(0.5) = 0, not 2!

Comment: I see what you're saying. This is really not my area however just one last question please. They run a regression where the independent variable is this transformed fraction and the coefficient is -0.0095. They say that a one standard deviation increase in the fraction of the people that cycle will reduce the dependent variable by 1.1% per year. What I am trying to understand if possible is what this one standard deviation actually translates into in real terms if you know what I mean? For instance what magnitude of increase in cycling would we have to see and/or how likely this is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49691/discussion-between-user43849-and-vladmir-putin).